# Where can I find a list of states, districts and tehsil names in India?

Tags: data, india

I need only names for making a chained dropdown list for users to select location correctly and submit the data.
Please provide any resources.
I emailed censusindia.gov.in but no reply from them.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on my Comment, You should download the Administrative Atlas from here: http://censusindia.gov.in/2011census/maps/maps2011.html

This has the data for all sub districts in India. It might not be an easy to extract format, but this is as official and exhaustive an list that you are going to get.

You should know that division of districts is not uniform across India. In some states they are called Tehesils, somewhere else they are called Taluks, in A.P. They are called Mandals, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the information,but i can't use information available on that site in commercial website.Asked them for permission but no reply.Looking for free source.

Comment: If you want freely available data that is accurate, and allows commercial use, you are going to have a hard time. Not even GDAM allows Commercial usage of Data. Your best bet might be to purchase a DVD from Census Of India. I know that it allows commercial usage.

Answer (score 3):

I found more updated data in different formats

at http://questionbox.in/india-state-district-sub-district-database-in-excel-csv-and-sql-query-format/

Answer (score 2):

Additional resources for subnational spatial data are available [on this page](http://devecondata.blogspot.ch/2007/09/administrative-boundaries.html).

You can try the [GAUL dataset](http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/metadata.show?id=12691&currTab=simple), which provides yearly updates of administrative divisions at a global scale from 1990 to 2013.

Answer (score 1):

The gadm datasets from http://www.gadm.org/country include level 0 to level 3 geometries with names in the attribute tables.
Level 0 is the whole India, 1 to 3 the subdivisions.

The Shapefile datasets contain csv and dbf files with the information you can use without GIS software. Level 3 include the names of the corresponding higher levels as well.

Comment: While GDAM is a wonderful resource, unfortunately the level 2 and level 3 data is woefully dated in certain regions of India, and totally wrong in some other parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try Indian-State-City-db-json .It is a comprehensive json data of cities with the different states as keys.

for ex: {[Uttar Pradesh: Lucknow, Kanpur, Agra ...],[Karnataka: Surathkal, Bangalore ]...}

Here is the github link : https://github.com/shauryashahi/Indian-State-City-db-json

Answer (score 1):

I found states, districts and tehsil info from the below path and the details are upto date.... You can check it here. 
http://egreenwatch.nic.in/Masters/Public/TehsilView.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found states, districts and tehsil info from the below path and the details are upto date (as of Aug 2015)

http://questionbox.in/india-state-district-sub-district-database-in-excel-csv-and-sql-query-format/